# Worksheet_Change not working on Virtualized Win Server SP2

Tags: excel, vba, windows-server-2008-r2

I have a problem with an code I have written that is running smoothly on my Desktop Excel app however it is failing on Citrix Windows Server 2008 Excel, I hope somebody could help me.

The worksheet is unable to trigger the Worksheet_Change event to trigger the macro.

This file should execute some validation code when there is a change on some specific columns of the sheet so I used Worksheet_Change. The code I wrote works perfectly on my desktop Excel App and any desktop Excel of my peers, but when I tested the same code over our Citrix the Worksheet_Change just doesn't trigger.

I have tried some of the common found answer over forums, activated the application.enableevents, checking macro security settings but nothings seems to work.

This Code is placed on sheets("COM") Worksheet:

````
Public Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False

Dim COM As Worksheet
    Set COM = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("COM")

On Error Resume Next
COM.Unprotect Password:="****"
On Error GoTo 0

Dim ResColumn As Long
Dim SubResColumn As Long
Dim HeaderRow As Long, Startrow As Long, EndRow As Long
        HeaderRow = Sheets("COM").Range("D1").End(xlDown).Row
        ResColumn = Sheets("COM").Range("A" & HeaderRow & ":AZ" & HeaderRow).Find("RES", LookIn:=xlValues, LOOKAT:=xlWhole).Column

If Not Intersect(Target, Sheets("COM").Columns(ResColumn)) Is Nothing Then


'Code to be executed



End If

On Error Resume Next
COM .Protect Password:="****", AllowFiltering:=True
On Error GoTo 0

Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.CutCopyMode = False
'Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```
````

Comment: Not a solution to the problem, but a recommendation for readability. Since this is in a sheet code module, you can get rid of `Dim COM...`, `Set COM` and so on and just use `Me`.

Comment: Is the `101` above an `On Error Resume Next` a typo?

Comment: 101 removed, it was just to skip some part of the code if necessary.

Comment: Macro security settings can be weird on a server.  If possible, try opening the file as Administrator instead of just double-clicking it and see if that helps.  If issue persists, make sure the file isn't blocked (check the file properties).  If still having an issue, hard to say without being able to troubleshoot with you.

Comment: Can you run *any* macros in that environment?  Just a simple `Msgbox "OK"`  for example?

Comment: @tigeravatar Thank you for your comment, I will contact my administrator and see if it is it. that would be and dead-end problem as the user that would use it won't have admin rights.

Comment: @TimWilliams Yes, I can call userforms without problems, and also was able to retrived and send data from an Access database with macro, however the validation part that should be execute automatically is not working. I guess I would need to call it before data is send to database, instead of it automatically run as the user is entering the data.